# Bad Credentials with Login form from Spring Security

Tags: authentication, spring-security, credentials

I have a problem with logining to my app.

I use Spring Security and its `formLogin()` and BCrypt Encoder.

I create register page in html and this works good. I can register and my user save to my database, but
when I want login on my page. I can't. I saw `Bad Credentials` and that's for any user.

Can you help me?

https://github.com/Bartosz777/mylibrary    <- this my github with this project.

When I try to login in `localhost:8080/login` in my console I see

```
Hibernate: 
select user0_.id as id1_3_, user0_.email as email2_3_, 
   user0_.is_enabled as is_enabl3_3_, user0_.password as password4_3_, 
   user0_.role as role5_3_, user0_.username as username6_3_ 
from user user0_ 
where user0_.username=?
________________________________________________________________________________
UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE 

**2020-06-22 19:28:30.520 DEBUG 16804 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authentication failed: password does not match stored value
2020-06-22 19:28:30.521 DEBUG 16804 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials**


That's I have after logining to my app. Do you know why?
```

Comment: I did that and I got this log

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I tried register again but it doesn't works, problem appeared again.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai https://github.com/Bartosz777/Rest-APP/tree/master/src/main/java/com/crud/restapp/tasks/config I have second app with the same config and login works

Answer (score 2):

At your `WebSecurityConfig` you have to also set the `passwordEncoder` to the `AuthenticationManagerBuild`, something like this:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```